# PHP code seems to skip the "if" statement

Tags: php, scripting

I am familiar with writing bash scripts, but PHP is new to me.

I have the following code which is executed with variables loaded from a HTML form (also learned in the last week), and the code works if I enter a domain name to do lookup against it, however, if the form tried to do a lookup against an IP address only, it doesn't work.  It seems to skip the entire "else" part of the code. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');
if(isset($_GET['subject1'], $_GET['subject2'])) {

    $text1 = $_GET['subject1'];
    $text2 = $_GET['subject2'];

    $text1 = escapeshellarg($text1);
    $text2 = escapeshellarg($text2);
    echo "THE VARIABLES THAT YOU HAVE SUBMITTED ARE "  . "\n";
    echo "You entered $text1 for the Domain Name "  . "\n";
    echo "You entered $text2 for the IP Address "  . "\n";
    echo "\n";
}

if (!empty($text1)) {
    $command1 = '/usr/bin/dig ' . '@localhost ' . "$text1 " . "+short " . "| /usr/bin/tail -n1" . "\n";
    echo "\n";
    echo "THE COMMAND THAT YOU HAVE SUBMITTED WILL THEREFORE BE "  . "\n";
    print_r($command1) . "\n";
    echo "\n";
    $output1 = shell_exec($command1);
    echo "\n";
    echo "RESULTS OF A EXTERNAL DNS (NAME TO IP) LOOKUP FOR THE DOMAIN ENTERED" . "\n";
    echo "$output1";
    echo "\n";

    $command2 = '/usr/bin/whois ' . "$text1" . "\n";
    echo "\n";
    $output2 = shell_exec($command2);
    echo "\n";
    echo "RESULTS OF A WHOIS LOOKUP AGAINST " . "$text1 " . "\n";
    echo "$output2";
    echo "\n";

    $command3 = '/usr/bin/whois ' . "$output1" . "\n";
    echo "\n";
    $output3 = shell_exec($command3);
    echo "\n";
    echo "RESULTS OF A WHOIS LOOKUP AGAINST " . "$output1 " . "\n";
    echo "$output3";
    echo "\n";
    goto END;

} else {

    $command4 = '/usr/bin/whois ' . "$text2" . "\n";
    echo "\n";
    $output4 = shell_exec($command4);
    echo "\n";
    echo "RESULTS OF A WHOIS LOOKUP AGAINST " . "$text2 " . "\n";
    echo "$output4";
    echo "\n";
    goto END;
}
END:
echo "END OF THE TEST RESULTS " . "\n";
?>
```

The name lookups work, but the ip address section is skipped in its entirety.

Comment: What input values did you supply to the script? And then what output did you see? What output did you expect instead, for those inputs? Please provide samples to demonstrate the issue. And what debugging have you attempted so far? Is php error reporting enabled? Please [edit] your post to clarify these points so we can help you more easily. Thanks

Comment: I think it might be because you're using `escapeshellarg` - if you pass an empty string (ie an empty `$text1`) to this function, it produces `''` (a string with two single quotes).  That's a string that's no longer 'empty' in PHP terms, so the first branch of your `if` statement always executes.  I would suggest only escaping things at the point that you need to - ie only when you're constructing your shell statement - and not before.

Comment: The input value will be a domain name for $text1 OR an IP address for $text2.  If $text1 is empty, then I expect it to carry out command 4 against $text2, which is the IP address.  As i have mentioned, command 1 to 3 work fine against a doamin name, however, command 4 never runs and i cant work out why.

Comment: @ Rob Eyre, so whats my fix here, as this sounds like it might well me the issue.

Comment: Move the `escapeshellarg` command to the point in your code where you're actually creating a shell command - don't call it before you need it, because it's turning an empty string into a `''`

Comment: Rob said `I would suggest only escaping things at the point that you need to - ie only when you're constructing your shell statement - and not before`...so that's likely the solution. Don't escape anything before the `if`, certainly. If you put `var_dump($text1);` just before the `if` you can see what the value is and therefore predict what the `if (!empty($text1)) {
` will do.

Comment: P.S. `however, command 4 never runs`...presumably though it tried to run the other commands instead when you expected it to run command 4?  You only described what it didn't do, not what it did instead. That kind of info is always very helpful when you are debugging.

Comment: P.p.s. Here's a great guide to debugging your php code: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.atatus.com/blog/php-debugging/amp/ -It seems like maybe you're not familiar with the basics of testing and fault finding, which you need to be confident with in order to solve even basic issues in your code.

Comment: @RobEyre You were bang on with the statement "That's a string that's no longer 'empty' in PHP terms".  So i moved $text1 = escapeshellarg($text1); to before command1 and moved $text1 = escapeshellarg($text2); to before command4 so that all of this is done after the logical test, and it all works as expected.  Many thanks to all for your help.

Comment: @ADyson, "It seems like maybe you're not familiar with the basics of testing and fault finding", again you are bang on.  I only started learning this a week ago, so thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Probably $text1 does not evalue to empty. Echo $text1 and $text2 between your if blocks, so you could confirm that. If it's that, change the if (!empty($text1)) for something else which adjusts to the input values you'll receive.

Comment: Thi is what i see when i run an IP Address only query:-THE VARIABLES THAT YOU HAVE SUBMITTED ARE 
You entered '' for the Domain Name 
You entered '142.250.180.3' for the IP Address

Comment: Well, '' does not equals to empty. You could go with strlen($text1) > 0 for example.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you give an if statement -
if $text1 is not empty it will  do this

```
$command1 = '/usr/bin/dig ' . '@localhost ' . "$text1 " . "+short " . "| /usr/bin/tail -n1" . "\n";
    echo "\n";
    echo "THE COMMAND THAT YOU HAVE SUBMITTED WILL THEREFORE BE "  . "\n";
    print_r($command1) . "\n";
    echo "\n";
    $output1 = shell_exec($command1);
    echo "\n";
    echo "RESULTS OF A EXTERNAL DNS (NAME TO IP) LOOKUP FOR THE DOMAIN ENTERED" . "\n";
    echo "$output1";
    echo "\n";

    $command2 = '/usr/bin/whois ' . "$text1" . "\n";
    echo "\n";
    $output2 = shell_exec($command2);
    echo "\n";
    echo "RESULTS OF A WHOIS LOOKUP AGAINST " . "$text1 " . "\n";
    echo "$output2";
    echo "\n";

    $command3 = '/usr/bin/whois ' . "$output1" . "\n";
    echo "\n";
    $output3 = shell_exec($command3);
    echo "\n";
    echo "RESULTS OF A WHOIS LOOKUP AGAINST " . "$output1 " . "\n";
    echo "$output3";
    echo "\n";
    goto END;
```

and else $text1 is empty then your IP address section will work.

Comment: Thats is exactly how it is expected to work.  If i supply a domain name ($text1) all works as you might expect (carries out command 1-3), however, if you only supply an IP address ($text2), then it doesnt do whats expected(command 4).  Its confusing me.

Comment: I think that you are all correct in you assessment of '' is not an empty string.  Ill give some of the suggestions a go and let you knwo how i get on